# Laravel 4 DB seed issue

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am trying to create a database seed file. Here how is it:

```
class UsersSeeder extends DatabaseSeeder {

public function run()
{
    $users = [
        [
            'email' => 'mymail@mail.com',
            'password' => Hash::make('123456'),
            'name' => 'Admin'
        ]
     ];

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        User::create($user);
    }
}

}
```

When I run the `artisan db:seed`, I got this error message:

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in E:\www\laravel4\app\datab
ase\seeds\UsersSeeder.php`

I don't see any error on my script. How can I solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using a PHP version below [PHP 5.4.0](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) on your CLI (run `php -v` to be sure).
Thus the short JSON-like array notation isn't supported. you should use `array()` instead (or upgrade).

```
$users = array (
      array  (
            'email' => 'mymail@mail.com',
            'password' => Hash::make('123456'),
            'name' => 'Admin'
        )
     );
```